# ClosedXML - Carriage Return Within a Cell

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I generate an Excel file with ClosedXML and I want to know how can I do a Carriage Return Within a Cell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` to add a "carriage return" to a cell's value.

Comment: "Simply concatenate " + `Environment.NewLine` + " into a string";
This works for text in Comments also.